# Spring Security disable rememberMe doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have Spring Boot application. It is necessary to send `Authorization` header on every request otherwise deny access to resource.

But if I made request with this header once I can send requests without it and receive content of resource. Why? Where am I wrong in code?

Spring Security configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .rememberMe().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and()
            .httpBasic().and()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .logout().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("1").password("1").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Controller:

```java
    @RestController
    public class FooController {

        @RequestMapping("/foo")
        public Bar bar() {
            Bar bar = new Bar();
            return bar;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably your client sends a session cookie. You can use [SessionCreationPolicyl#STATELESS](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/http/SessionCreationPolicy.html#STATELESS) to not use HTTP session for authentication.

Answer (score 3):

```
    http
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
```

Disable create session. [Session Management](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#sessionManagement%28%29)

Comment: Worked like a charm !!